# I have got problem clicking on hidden element

Tags: python, selenium

I have got a problem with my code because I am not able to click on a hidden element can someone help me?

[image]

The first picture is while hovering over and second it without hover

```
# webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\chromedriver.exe')

#zmazat prvý inzerat
[enter image description here][2]browser.get('https://www.bazos.sk/moje-inzeraty.php?mail=&telefon=0944668585&Submit=Vyp%C3%ADsa%C5%A5+inzer%C3%A1ty')


element_to_hover_over =         browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()

zmazat = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Zmazať/Upraviť/Topovať')]")
time.sleep(1)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", zmazat);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the element "zmazat" try this xpath
e.g.

```
zmazat = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Zmazať/Upraviť/Topovať') and @class='akce']")
```